# Rotate a triangle around point such that opposite side is horizontal

Tags: geometry

I have a triangle A-B-C.  By what angle do I rotate B and C around A such that C' and B' are horizontal?  That is, what is the angle B-A-B'?

[image: see example here]

Comment: Is this two-dimensional space?

Comment: Yes, two-dimensional

Comment: Do you have the coordinates of each of the points? Or how do you define the points?

Comment: So essentially you are interested in the angle that the vector $\vec{AB}$ makes with the horizontal axis (that has the direction vector $\hat{i}$). The easiest way to calculate this angle is with the dot product
$$
\vec{AB} \cdot \hat{i} = \cos{\theta}
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.

Comment: The coordinates of each point are known